# how validate empty controls in windowsform

Tags: c#, errorprovider

i create  a windows form with multi controls (text box & date time picker & combo box)
then use error provider to check if a control is empty or not (14 of controls must be filled), with a messy code to check (14 if statement on the save button event) it shows the errors but stores the form in database.
how can i prevent save button to insert the form whiteout any of this 14 controls

[image: red Square shows controls that needs to be saved]

Comment: Please provide save button code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my problem solved by validating event .

under validating event of each control that need to be filled`

```
  private void cmb_nof_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
       Validatecmb_nof();
    }
    private bool Validatecmb_nof()
    {

        bool bstatus = true;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmb_nof.Text))
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(cmb_nof, "item required");
            bstatus = false;
        }
        else
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(cmb_nof, "");
        }
        return bstatus;
    }
```

`and under saver button click event  this code

```
            bool Valnof = Validatecmb_nof();

            if ( Valnof )
            {       
            //some events   
              }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid data");
            }
```